# expected unqualified id before '\0'

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, typedef

I tried following things but I am getting the error

```
typedef '\0' DEFAULT_VALUE;
```

> Error: expected unqalified id before '\0'`

```
typedef NULL DEFAULT_VALUE;
```

> Error: expected unqalified id before __null

what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The keyword `typedef` defines synonym for existing type. Neither `\0` nor `NULL` are **type**. May be you want something as follows:

```
#define DEFAULT_VALUE NULL
```

Comment: Since the question is tagged C++ you should avoid the `#define` and use the `const int` construct. Preprocessor macros just replace source text, while C++ offers type safety that you cannot achieve with the macros.

Comment: @harper: true. i haven't noticed that the question is tagged C++. from OP's question i guessed s/he is trying to do something like `#define`.

Answer (score 6):

The general syntax of a `typedef` is:

```
typedef existing_type new_type_name ;
```

Since `'\0'` and `NULL` are not existing **types** you get the error.

Since you want define constants you can use the `const` as:

```
const int DEFAULT_VALUE = '\0';
```

Comment: so i can assign a pointer after that as...int *ptr = DEFAULT_VALUE.?